# Laravel: How can I retrieve a list of users who have a particular role in this example?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

**User Migration:**

```
/**
     * Users
     */
    Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $t) {
        $t->increments('id');
        $t->string('email', 100)->unique();
        $t->string('password', 60);
        $t->string('firstname', 30);
        $t->string('lastname', 30);
        $t->string('company', 60)->nullable();
        $t->string('phone')->nullable();
        $t->rememberToken();
        $t->timestamps();
    });
```

**Role Migration:**

```
Schema::create('roles', function(Blueprint $t) {
        $t->increments('id');
        $t->string('name', 30)->unique();
    });
```

**Pivot Table:**

```
Schema::create('role_user', function(Blueprint $t) {
            $t->increments('id');
            $t->integer('role_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $t->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');

            $t->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $t->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

The relationship is working fine, but I need to retrieve a list of all users who have a particular role, lets say "Agent"

Ultimately I want to add this user list to a Form::select, so I will need only *id, firstname, lastname* fields from the users table.

**OK, After typing all of that, I figured this out. Wanted to still submit in case someone else finds it helpful, or shows me a better way. Below is working:**

I first added this to the User model:

public function getFullNameAttribute()
{
    return $this->attributes['firstname'] . ' ' . $this->attributes['lastname'];
}

Then I receive prepare the data in the controller:

```
$agents = User::select('firstname', 'lastname', 'id')->with(['roles' => function($query) {
    $query->where('name', 'Agent');
}])->get();

$agentsList = $agents->lists('fullName', 'id');
```

That seems to work, but I am not sure if it is a proper way to handle it. The page is rarely ever used, so performance wont matter much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this, `whereHas` will fetch only those with `name=Agent` but with will fetch all:

```
$agents = User::whereHas('roles', function($query) {
    $query->where('name', 'Agent');
})->get(['firstname', 'lastname', 'id'])->lists('fullName', 'id');
```